# NSMapTable missing from 3.0 headers?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm using NSMapTable in a program that must run under both 3.0 and 2.2.1. As expected, the program compiles without problems for the 2.2.1 libraries, but when I switch to 3.0, I get compiler errors:

```
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'NSMapTable'
```

In other words, XCode can't find the declaration of the NSMapTable class. I had to put in a forward declaration (@class NSMapTable) in my own header and

```
#import <Foundation/NSMapTable.h>
```

in my implementation file in order to be able to use NSMapTable.

Any explanations for this? Or is it just a bug, plain and simple?

(I should point out that I do, of course, have #import  in the header file of the class that uses NSMapTable, but still need the specific import.)

Comment: For anyone who would try to use NSMapTable on the iPhone, here is a quick and easy way of replacing it with a dictionary for one simple case (where the key doesn't conform to NSCopying).

Instead of:
NSMapTable* mt = [NSMapTable mapTableWithWeakToWeakObjects];
[mt setObject:theObj forKey:theKey];

do:
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:100];
[dict setObject:theObj forKey:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:theKey]];

Comment: You could also use CFMutableDictionary: CFDictionaryKeyCallBacks keyCallbacks = {0}; CFMutableDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &keyCallbacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks); CFDictionarySetValue(dict, key, value); value = (id)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, key);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe NSMapTable was available on 2.2 for apps compiled for "Device", either; it was only available on "Simulator".  Since 3.0's simulator is a more accurate representation of the device, that header is no longer available.  Fortunately, you can do much of what an NSMapTable can do with an NSDictionary and appropriate NSValue or NSNumber wrapper objects around keys and values.

Comment: Thanks. A clear sign that I should be less lazy about testing on a device often. But why did it compile for 3.0 simulator when I put in the extra #include?

Comment: In Foundation/Foundation.h, that include is wrapped in "#if (TARGET_OS_MAC && !(TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE))".  In other words, it works because there's nothing in NSMapTable.h itself to indicate that it isn't available on the iPhone.